# Is working set equivalent to solution in the visual studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, eclipse

To Anyone familiar with both, is Eclipse working set equivalent to solution in the visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A [Visual Studio solution](http://www.ucertify.com/article/what-is-a-solution-in-visual-studio-net.html) is about grouping related projects together.
If anything, it could be equivalent to a collection of Eclipse `.project` files (provided that those projects declare dependencies to other projects within that group).

An [Eclipse WorkingSet](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_workingsets.htm) is about **resource filtering** (which view/commands/actions are displayed in a given working set): it can contains any number of projects, which can be completely unrelated one with another.